# Exclude one folder named components but not another

Tags: git, github

I want to exclude the components directory in my base folder but not any other components directory:

```
/components --- WANT EXCLUDED
/client/components --- WANT INCLUDED
```

What should my .gitignore look like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do /components in .gitignore

Answer (score 1):

You can add exceptions by prepending the `!`

So for your case, the .gitignore file will look like

```
components
!/client/components
```